# makemigrations failing after moving from Windows to Linux with Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a small web app (using Postgres) that I have been developing in a Django Windows environment and it is working fine.  I'm now trying to move it to Redhat 6.8 and makemigrations is failing.
I've installed Postgres and created the database on Linux.  I created the database new because I didn't need any of the old test data on Windows.  I moved over all of the files (except the .pyc files).  Below is the error I'm getting.  It seems it is trying to access a table that is not yet created. (It's not yet created because I haven't been able to run a migration yet( sort of a chicken/egg paradigm).  Note, from what I've read, I also removed all of the migrations files except **init**.py.  I've been wrestling with this for many hours.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

```
    webtest2) [asilver@SDNAUTOS02 sdnlabs2]$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    self.check()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/regi
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls
    return check_method()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.p
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.p
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.p
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_modul
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/sdnlabs2/urls.py", line 24
    url(r'^inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_modul
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/urls.py", line 3
    from . import views
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/views.py", line
    from .filters import *
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/filters.py", lin
    class PerfvRtrOnlyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/filters.py", lin
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/lib.py", line 20
    y = set(querySet)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.
    for row in compiler.results_iter(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch):
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/co
    results = self.execute_sql(MULTI, chunked_fetch=chunked_fetch)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/co
    raise original_exception
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "inventory_perfvrtronly" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "inventory_perfvrtronly"."topoName" FROM "inventory_p...
                                                        ^

(webtest2) [asilver@SDNAUTOS02 sdnlabs2]$
```

Comment: If you have a doubt about your migration, you can always try to delete all your `migrations` directories on your local environment and then do a `python manage.py migrate` it will recreate a proper migration script. But that mean that you cannot use a dump from previously because it will remember the old migrations scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Your PerfvRtrOnlyFilter class is trying to perform a query at class level, which means it runs even the class is first imported. This is before any migration can run.

You just always do any database access inside a method or function.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm using django_filters here and I believe I'm implementing this similar to the examples in the documentation.  I could post the code for entire class definition if you think that would be helpful.  In that class definition, I am referencing a function called "get_unique_choice" that I wrote.  That function is located in the lib.py file. Are you saying I shouldn't be doing that?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes you should post the code. You certainly shouldn't be calling that function at class level

Answer (score 0):

The two suggestions I received seemed very similar to so I tried the one with the listed out instructions.  I could not get past 2nd step above.  I unregistered the app and then tried running migrate but got different errors this time. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/sdnlabs2/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^inventory/', include('inventory.urls')),
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/views.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .tables import DeviceInstanceTable, PerfvRtrOnlyTable, HardwareTable
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/tables.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .models import DeviceInstance, PerfvRtrOnly, Hardware
  File "/home/asilver/pythonProjects/django/sdntest2/sdnweb/sdnlabs2/inventory/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class Hardware(models.Model):
  File "/home/asilver/.virtualenvs/webtest2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 118, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class inventory.models.Hardware doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Here is the code for that class:

```
class PerfvRtrOnlyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    deviceName = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name='deviceName', label='Device', queryset=DeviceInstance.objects.all())
    hardware = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name='hardware', label='Hardware', queryset=Hardware.objects.all())
    jdmVersion = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name='jdmVersion', label='JDM Version', queryset=Software.objects.all().filter(component__function='hypervisor'))
    vrtrVersion = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name='vrtrVersion', label='vRTR Version', queryset=Software.objects.filter(component__function='vrtr'))
    vrtr = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(name='vrtr', label='vRouter', queryset=Component.objects.filter(function='vrtr'))
    jflow = django_filters.BooleanFilter(name='jflow', label='Jflow')

    ##################################################
    # Mulitple Choice Filter for topoName
    ##################################################
    partial_query_set = PerfvRtrOnly.objects.values_list('topoName')
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
    topoName = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=choiceList, label='Topology')

    ##################################################
    # Mulitple Choice Filter for frameSize
    ##################################################
    partial_query_set = PerfvRtrOnly.objects.values_list('frameSize')
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
    frameSize = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=choiceList, label='Frame Size')

    ##################################################
    # Mulitple Choice Filter for Run Date
    ##################################################
    partial_query_set = PerfvRtrOnly.objects.values_list('runDate')
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
    runDate = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=choiceList, label='Run Date')

    ##################################################
    # Single Choice Filter for Bridging Technology
    ##################################################
    partial_query_set = PerfvRtrOnly.objects.values_list('bridgeTech')
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
    bridgeTech = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=choiceList, label='Bridge Tech')

    ##################################################
    # Mulitple Choice Filter for Traffic Type
    ##################################################
    partial_query_set = PerfvRtrOnly.objects.values_list('trafficType')
    choiceList = get_unique_choice_list(partial_query_set)
    trafficType = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=choiceList, label='Traffic Type')

    class Meta:
        model = PerfvRtrOnly
        fields = ['qos', 'officialRun',]
```

Here is the code for the function "get_unique_choice_list" which resides in the file lib.py:

```
#####################################################################################
# This function is used to create a choice list for a filter in filter.py
# querySet is a querySet object and it should only contain one field of the table
# There may be duplicate entries in that list and each item in the list is a tupple.
#####################################################################################
def get_unique_choice_list(querySet):

    list_1= []
    y = set(querySet)
    for i in y:
        list_1.append(i)

    ######################################################################################################
    # At this point we have a list of tuples which is no good.  Ultiimately we need a tuple of tuples...
    # As show below in the example. An enumerated tuple
    # If we print list_1 we have this at this point:
    #In [38]: print list_1
    # [(u'J1101',), (u'D1001',), (u'H1101',), (u'D1',), (u'G1',), (u'G1001',)]
    ######################################################################################################
        list_2 = []
    for i in list_1:
        a = i[0]
        list_2.append(a)

    list_2.sort()
    #######################################################################
    # At this point we should have a list of topologies and no more tuples
    # print list_2
    # [u'J1101', u'D1001', u'H1101', u'D1', u'G1', u'G1001']
    #######################################################################


    #######################################################################
    # We now need to create a list of tuples
    #######################################################################
    list_3 = []
    for i in list_2:
        new_item = (str(i),str(i))
        list_3.append(new_item)

    return list_3
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working but needed brute force to do it.  I removed all of the files in the django app and started a new project and app.  Then I added the models.py file and updated the settings.py file.  At that point I ran makemigrations and everything worked.  Lastly, I re-added the rest of my files to the project and all is working now...  At least for now.  We'll see what happens next time I make any model changes and issue the makemigrations command again....

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

- Unregister your app from settings.py
- Run python manage.py migrate
- Register your app back
- Remove ( keep backup ) the migration folder from your app
- Run python manage.py makemigrations
- Than python manage.py migrate

Comment: I tried your steps above but could not get past the second step.  When I tried to run the migrate command it did not work w